# Scala Lift - Stream an image from server

Tags: image, scala, lift

I have a simple upload system that saves a file to the root of the server (e.g C:/files), obviously I need to read the file in with scala from the path and then some how make it accessible from a simple path in an image tag, like:

```
<img src="/files/test.jpg" />
```

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is serve up the raw files, then follow [Odomontois's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9499876/115478) and just serve up that file location using [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/).

Presumably, though, you want to do something more than just that (access control, filtering, etc.). In that case, I would recommend building a [RESTful service](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-5.html#toc-Chapter-5) that uses a [`StreamingResponse`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.http.StreamingResponse).

The use of `StreamingResponse` is important; otherwise large files could cause out-of-memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure but I would start by looking at manipulating LiftRules in your Boot class to tell Lift to serve images from C:/files.  Or you could try moving the files from C:/files to /images where they will get served automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Best option here is to install [apache](http://www.apache.org/) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) server to nice serve static files. With that you could upstream lift server to target HTTP server, maintain load balancing, etc.